# Cant figure out what Im doing wrong. Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'inspection' of undefined

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object

so I have a eventhandler that calls for data from an Api.
Now Im writing a function that formats the incoming data.

```
eventHandlers={{
            dragend : async (e)=>{
              const lat = e.target._latlng.lat;
              const lng = e.target._latlng.lng;
              const result = await callSodaApi(lat, lng);
              const data = consolidate(result.data);   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-
              console.log(data);
              setMapConfig({
                markerCoord : [lat, lng],
                queryData : result.data
              });
            },
          }}
```

the incoming data looks like this :
this example before is from the same restaurant, but could also be a different restaurant differentiate by the key camis.

```
{
  action: "D"
  boro: "Manhattan"
  building: "625"
  camis: "40363298"
  critical_flag: "G"
  cuisine_description: "American"
  dba: "CAFE METRO"
  grade: "A"
  grade_date: "2016-05-13T00:00:00.000"
  inspection_date: "2016-05-13T00:00:00.000"
  inspection_type: "Cycle Inspection / Initial Inspection"
  latitude: "40.756185423077"
  longitude: "-73.990564733785"
  record_date: "2021-05-29T06:03:39.000"
  score: "4"
  street: "8 AVENUE"
  violation_code: "10E"
  violation_description: "Accurate thermometer not provided in refrigerated or hot holding equipment."
  zipcode: "10018"
},
{
  action: "U"
  boro: "Manhattan"
  building: "625"
  camis: "40363298"
  critical_flag: "C"
  cuisine_description: "American"
  dba: "CAFE METRO"
  grade: "A"
  grade_date: "2017-10-10T00:00:00.000"
  inspection_date: "2017-10-10T00:00:00.000"
  inspection_type: "Cycle Inspection / Re-inspection"
  latitude: "40.756185423077"
  longitude: "-73.990564733785"
  phone: "2127149342"
  record_date: "2021-05-29T06:03:39.000"
  score: "12"
  street: "8 AVENUE"
  violation_code: "04H"
  violation_description: "Raw, cooked or prepared food is adulterated, contaminated, cross-contaminated, or not discarded in accordance with HACCP plan."
  zipcode: "10018"
}
```

if they are the same restaurant, I want to combine the different violations from the same restaurant under the same object with new violation key. Like the code below.

```
{
  action: "U"
  boro: "Manhattan"
  building: "625"
  camis: "40363298"
  critical_flag: "C"
  cuisine_description: "American"
  dba: "CAFE METRO"
  grade: "A"
  grade_date: "2017-10-10T00:00:00.000"
  latitude: "40.756185423077"
  longitude: "-73.990564733785"
  phone: "2127149342"
  record_date: "2021-05-29T06:03:39.000"
  score: "12"
  street: "8 AVENUE"
  violation: [{
        date: "2016-05-13T00:00:00.000"
        type: "Cycle Inspection / Initial Inspection"
        violation_code: "04H"
  violation_description: "Raw, cooked or prepared food is adulterated, contaminated, cross-contaminated, or not discarded in accordance with HACCP plan."/
         },{
        date: "2017-10-10T00:00:00.000"
        type: "Cycle Inspection / Re-inspection"
        violation_code: "04H"
        violation_description: "Raw, cooked or prepared food is adulterated, contaminated, cross-contaminated, or not discarded in accordance with HACCP plan."
}]
  zipcode: "10018"
}
```

this is the function I wrote,

```
const consolidate = (dataArray) => {
  let a = 0;
  let nxt = 1;
  let holdingArray = [];

  while ( nxt < dataArray.length-1 ) {
    let newObj;
    // if same restaurant
    if ( dataArray[a].camis === dataArray[nxt].camis ) {
    // when this is the first iteration of restaruant 
      newObj = nxt - a === 1
        ? {
            camis: dataArray[a].camis,
            dba: dataArray[a].dba,
            cuisine: dataArray[a].cuisine_description,
            building: dataArray[a].building,
            street: dataArray[a].street,
            boro: dataArray[a].boro,
            zipcode: dataArray[a].zipcode,
            grade : dataArray[a].grade || dataArray[nxt].grade,
            latitude: dataArray[a].latitude,
            longitude: dataArray[a].longitude,
            inspection: 
              [ {
                date: dataArray[a].inspection_date,
                type: dataArray[a].inspection_type,
                violation_code: dataArray[a].violation_code,
                violation_description: dataArray[a].violation_description

              }, {
                date: dataArray[nxt].inspection_date,
                type: dataArray[nxt].inspection_type,
                violation_code: dataArray[nxt].violation_code,
                violation_description: dataArray[nxt].violation_description
              }]
        }
        : {
            camis: dataArray[a].camis,
            dba: dataArray[a].dba,
            cuisine: dataArray[a].cuisine_description,
            building: dataArray[a].building,
            street: dataArray[a].street,
            boro: dataArray[a].boro,
            zipcode: dataArray[a].zipcode,
            grade : dataArray[a].grade || dataArray[nxt].grade,
            latitude: dataArray[a].latitude,
            longitude: dataArray[a].longitude,
            inspection: [...newObj.inspection , {
                date: dataArray[nxt].inspection_date,
                type: dataArray[nxt].inspection_type,
                violation_code: dataArray[nxt].violation_code,
                violation_description: dataArray[nxt].violation_description
            }]
        };
        console.log(newObj) <<<<<<<<<<
        nxt ++; 
    } else {
      holdingArray.push(newObj);
      a = nxt;
      nxt = nxt + 1;
    };
  };

  return holdingArray;
};
```

I'm able to see the very first iteration from the console.log() in the console. But right after I would get a type error

[image]

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong please.
And Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should post the error as text and not image, for better readability and indexing by the web site's search engine

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip! I will definitely do in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd take a stab at your logic using `reduce`. It sets up a `violation` array for each object for consistency, and reduces the codebase considerably. If you're refining the objects beyond the violation array, that's pretty easy to add to this as well.

```js
let odata = [{
    action: "D",
    boro: "Manhattan",
    building: "625",
    camis: "40363298",
    critical_flag: "G",
    cuisine_description: "American",
    dba: "CAFE METRO",
    grade: "A",
    grade_date: "2016-05-13T00:00:00.000",
    inspection_date: "2016-05-13T00:00:00.000",
    inspection_type: "Cycle Inspection / Initial Inspection",
    latitude: "40.756185423077",
    longitude: "-73.990564733785",
    record_date: "2021-05-29T06:03:39.000",
    score: "4",
    street: "8 AVENUE",
    violation_code: "10E",
    violation_description: "Accurate thermometer not provided in refrigerated or hot holding equipment.",
    zipcode: "10018"
  },
  {
    action: "U",
    boro: "Manhattan",
    building: "625",
    camis: "40363298",
    critical_flag: "C",
    cuisine_description: "American",
    dba: "CAFE METRO",
    grade: "A",
    grade_date: "2017-10-10T00:00:00.000",
    inspection_date: "2017-10-10T00:00:00.000",
    inspection_type: "Cycle Inspection / Re-inspection",
    latitude: "40.756185423077",
    longitude: "-73.990564733785",
    phone: "2127149342",
    record_date: "2021-05-29T06:03:39.000",
    score: "12",
    street: "8 AVENUE",
    violation_code: "04H",
    violation_description: "Raw, cooked or prepared food is adulterated, contaminated, cross-contaminated, or not discarded in accordance with HACCP plan.",
    zipcode: "10018"
  }
]


let newdata = odata.reduce((final, obj) => {
  let vobj = {
    date: obj.inspection_date,
    type: obj.inspection_type,
    violation_code: obj.violation_code,
    violation_description: obj.violation_description
  }
  if (final[obj.camis]) final[obj.camis].violation.push(vobj)
  else final[obj.camis] = { ...obj,
    violation: [vobj]
  }
  return final;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(newdata))
```

Answer (score 1):

The faulty line is being pointed out in the error message. You are trying to access `inspection` on `newObj` before it was assigned.

For a better understanding, I've reproduced your error in this minimal code:

```js
let newObj;

newObj = {
    inspection: newObj.inspection // newObj is still undefined at this point
}
```